Vector databases - from an RDBMS perspective
Coming from an RDBMS background, I wanted to know more about vector databases.

Do vector databases have bulk upload and download features?
Suppose a vector database is downloaded into a .tar.gz file. Can this file be used to restore into the same vector database later?
Are vector databases portable? For example, download from say, Weaviate and upload to say, Pinecone?
Are there differences between an RDBMS client and a vector database client? For example, connecting, querying, inserting, deleting, etc. have different semantics across different vector databases?
Under the hood, are the vector databases clients just REST API clients?
Finally, are the content in a vector database dependent on the LLM that will respond to the prompt? For example, assume I have high school textbooks that I want to be stored in a vector database. Given a vector database, will the content differ if the prompts are made to say, Llama or Mistral, etc.?


Vector database = a table where one column is a vector, and other columns are the corresponding text and/or extra information (e.g., text ID).
One can store a vector database in an RDBMS or elsewhere.

So, all vector databases are RDBMS under the hood? (Over focusing on "table" word in your response). How about questions 3 - 6 above?

@cogitoergosum sorry, table/columns aren't a great choice of words. Could be stored in a NoSQL database too, or another format. Just need to keep track of the mapping between the vector and the text it represents.
